# SQL Server performance with FILESTREAM feature on

Tags: sql, sql-server, filestream, filetable

We have a large SQL Server instance, and we are planning to use FILETABLE in one of the new databases.  For using FILETABLE, we need to enable FILESTREAM feature at the SQL Server instance level with FILESTREAM access level settings.  We are worried if enabling the FILESTREAM option at the server instance level would negatively affect the overall performance of other databases in the instance even though they are not using the FILESTREAM feature.

Comment: Well, since enabling it requires a server restart, performance will at least briefly drop to 0. Beyond that, testing and measuring is your only recourse. There's only so much I/O to go around on a single server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. We have a Filestream enabled Database on our exceptionally heavily used Data Warehouse Server and we've never once seen ANY impact of the DB being FileStream enabled.

Now, what you  DO with that Filestreamed files is a totally different matter....

Comment: Spot on. If you never use the Filestream side, you'll see no impact. If you use it heavily you *may* see an impact, but you'd see the same (or worse) if you introduced a badly written, large, cursor driven stored proc. It's actually a pretty great feature.

Comment: Thanks Rachel and Dave.